# Configuring an Eclipse SourceViewer for Java

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I am trying to create a viewer that embeds a Java Editor/Viewer. However, I cannot get the Source Viewer to do the proper Java scanning & coloring. This is the code I have so far.

```
ScopedPreferenceStore store = new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE,
        ID);
JavaTextTools tools = new JavaTextTools(store);

Composite composite = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
composite.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));

viewer = new SourceViewer(composite, null, null, false, SWT.BORDER | SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
viewer.getTextWidget().setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));
viewer.setEditable(true);
viewer.getControl().setFont(JFaceResources.getFont(PreferenceConstants.EDITOR_TEXT_FONT));
Document document = new Document();
tools.setupJavaDocumentPartitioner(document);
viewer.setDocument(document);
viewer.configure(new JavaSourceViewerConfiguration(tools.getColorManager(), store, null,
        IJavaPartitions.JAVA_PARTITIONING));
```

Just amazed how hard it seem to just embed a simple Java editor ... Whatever I do, the viewer works but remains without any coloring.

Comment: JDT uses `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.JavaSourceViewer` you could look at that to see what it does.

Answer (score 0):

[`SourceViewer`](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/text/source/SourceViewer.html) is not a java editor, instead it's a class used to create source editors for custom languages as [described](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_annotations.htm) in the eclipse docs.

If you need just syntax coloring, then it might be easier to use `SourceViewer` and implement syntax coloring by yourself as described [here](https://help.eclipse.org/latest/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/editors_highlighting.htm).

Another option is use the actual java editor from eclipse as greg-449 [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/132147097).
But expect ***A LOT*** of code there.